# Why Dynamic Libary (.DLL) need Import Library (.LIB) to be referenced?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I wonder, working in Visual Studio, to call functions from a Dynamic library (`.DLL` file) by setting Project Reference, the Dynamic Library need generate Import Library (`.LIB`) files?

I understand that, working in Visual Studio, to call functions from a library (e.g. `MyLibrary`), there are two ways to configure -- Traditonally by adding `DLL` or `LIB` files in project depdendency, or alterntatively by defining Project Reference.

Traditionally, one needs add `DLL` or `LIB` file in caller project: in Project Property -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, add `MyLibrary.DLL/LIB;`; in Project Property -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories, add the folder that `MyLibrary.DLL/LIB` belongs to.

Alternatively, since Visual Studio 2012, one can add Project Reference in caller project: Project Property -> Common Properties -> Reference , add `MyLibrary` Project. However, it need generate `MyLibrary.LIB` file, here is the catch:

A) if `MyLibrary` is compiled as *static library*, it generates `MyLibrary.LIB`, no problem;

B) if `MyLibrary` is compiled as *dynamic library*, it generates `MyLibrary.DLL` by default, one needs to enable the dynamic library to generate *import library* (`.lib` files):  --

1) add the following code to `MyLibrary.h` file

```
#ifdef MyLibrary_EXPORTS
#define MyLibrary_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MyLibrary_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

, where `MyLibrary_EXPORTS` and `MyLibrary_API` are unique definitions for `MyLibrary` project.

2) Then, for each function of `MyLibrary` intend to export, simply precede by:
`MyLibrary_API`, e.g.

```
MyLibrary_API int TheAnswer(){return 42;}
```

3) Also, in `MyLibrary` preprocessors, define `MyLibrary_EXPORTS`.

My qestion is why there's such a difference?

Why in tradition way, by adding `.DLL` or `.LIB` files to caller project's dependencies, there's no difference to Static Library or Dynamic Library files; but in the Project Reference way, Dynamic Library need generate Import Library files (also `.LIB`)?

Comment: When you use static linking you can't handle that error from your app, if that dll failed to load but if you use dynamic linking you can handle that error. For example if you want to load foo.dll then you would call LoadLibrary. If that dll file was loaded successfully then it will return a valid handle else it will return NULL.

Comment: @Asesh are you answering my question that why DLL need generate LIB file to be referenced? maybe I shall update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Those lib files are used for static linking. If you use dynamic linking you don't need that lib file

Comment: I don't think Dynamic Library (.DLL file) can be static linked?

Comment: It can be. The Windows APIs that we use in our app are statically linked. For example, if you call GetWindowsDirectory whose implementation is in kernel32.dll then we would have to link to kernel32.lib: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Though we can dynamically link them too

Comment: I don't get your point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125831/discussion-between-asesh-and-athos).